# How to open Menu Options in .NET MAUI on long press

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui, maui-community-toolkit

How to open Menu Options in .NET MAUI on long press. Currently iPhone does this within photos like below video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1is7DjGFNWERy1xCx08j__kjc1ruQm1A-/view?usp=sharing

I want to implement this on Android and iOS devices. I am using [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-8.0) for rendering elements.

Is it possible in using .NET MAUI?

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal to include this in the MAUI Community Toolkit: [[Proposal] TouchEffect](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/86).

And you requirement is implementing this on the Android and iOS. So you can try to use the platform code to do that:

For the android, you can use the ImageView's Long Click event to do that. Such as:

```
#if ANDROID
   (image.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Widget.ImageView).LongClick +=(s,e)=>
   {
    //do something
   }
#end if
```

And you can also declare a [View.OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener) and then set the it for the image. Such as:

```
 public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnLongClickListener
    {
        public bool OnLongClick(Android.Views.View? v)
        {
           //do what you want here
        }
    }
=====
#if ANDROID
   (image.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Widget.ImageView).SetOnLongClickListener(new MyListener());
#end if
```

And for the ios, you can use the [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer):

```
#if IOS    
    (image.handler.PlatformView as UIKit.UIImageView).UserInteractionEnabled = true;  
    (image.handler.PlatformView as UIKit.UIImageView).AddGestureRecognizer(new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(MethodName()));  
#endif
```

And the effect after the long press, you can use the [popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) to do it.

Comment: Thank you. @Liyun Zhang  - MSFT. I am still working on this. I'll update when I found one solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Looking forward to your feedback. @AjayKumar